# QSqlDatabase connection

Tags: python, pyqt, mariadb, odbc, qsqldatabase

I have a server with a MariaDB Database.
Then I have a python program who run in a client where I have this code:

```
def Connect():
    
    #   Credential reading from register
    servHost = RegRead("servHost")
    servPort = RegRead("servPort")
    dbName = RegRead("dbName")
    __dbUser = RegRead("dbUser")
    __dbPass = RegRead("dbPass")

    con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC3')
    driver = "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};"
    database = f"Database={dbName};"
    databaseName = driver+database
    con.setDatabaseName(databaseName)
    con.setHostName(servHost)
    con.setPort(servPort)
    if con.open(__dbUser, __dbPass):
        print("Connected")
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I have made my program in a pc where I had both parts, so the database was in localhost and my pc was working as server and client at same time, then I changed it to a defined host. In my pc worked everything, but now that I have separeted server and client, I have problem to connect the client. The method Connect() return False and I don't understand what I am missing. I also remember that I installed a lot of things to let this work in my pc, but it was a lot of time ago and I don't remember what I did.
In the client, I have installed MariaDB ODBC Connector, I have the Driver "MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver" and made an User DNS who correctly connect to the database, but does not when it run in my program.
It run in my pc, so my code should be right. I think I missed some installation, maybe about Driver or some package, but I don't know what. Server is working too because I can make an User DNS. I did NOT install MariaDB Server (and I would not if not necessary). I have not installed anything except ODBC Connector and I imported only QSqlDatabase package.

Comment: I tried to disconnect my pc from the network with the server and I succesfully connected to database, so that mean that my pc is not connecting from a connection to `servHost` and `servPort`, but to localhost. To see if I wrongly read it from Register, I added a MessageBox who show me the credentials, but servHost and servPass are the one of my network server, so I think that `con.setHostName(servHost)` and `con.setPort(servPort)` are not working, but I don't know why

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add further details, don't use comments for that (unless somebody specifically asks you something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The method `setHostName` and the method `setPort` seem not to work. I think that it's because it require a QString object as parameter. I solved it adding the Host Name and Port to driver in this way

```
def Connect():
    
    #   Credential reading from register
    servHost = RegRead("servHost")
    servPort = RegRead("servPort")
    dbName = RegRead("dbName")
    __dbUser = RegRead("dbUser")
    __dbPass = RegRead("dbPass")

    con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC3')
    driver = "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};"+f"Server={servHost};Port={servPort};"    # This is the edit
    database = f"Database={dbName};"
    databaseName = driver+database
    con.setDatabaseName(databaseName)
    if con.open(__dbUser, __dbPass):
        print("Connected")
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Assuming you're using PyQt5, there's no QString, since PyQt automatically converts types (all references to QString in the C++ API docs should be considered as `str` in python), so I sincerely doubt that's the reason. It may be a bug, though, possibly caused by something else. What do `hostName()` and `port()` return right after calling `setHostName()` and `setPort()`?

Comment: I tried it right now and hostName() and port() return what I give as parameter to setHostName() and setPort(), but still working as explained. I solved it as I explained in the answer